# Given 2 generating functions for the sequences ($a_r$) and ($b_r$), show that $a_r$ = $b_{r+1}$ for each $r$ = 1, 2, ...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, generating-functions, multisets

Q: Let $a_r$ be the number of ways of distributing $r$ identical objects into 5 distinct boxes so that boxes 1, 3 and 5 are not empty. Let $b_r$ be the number of ways of distributing $r$ identical objects into 5 distinct boxes so that each of he boxes 2 and 4 contains at least two objects. Show that $a_r = b_{r+1}$ for each $r = 1, 2, ...$.

I have found the generating functions for the sequences ($a_r$) and ($b_r$) to be $x^3 $ $(\frac{1}{1-x})^5$ and $x^4 $ $(\frac{1}{1-x})^5$ respectively. What is exactly $b_{r+1}$ and how do I go about showing that $a_r = b_{r+1}$ for each $r = 1, 2, ...$? I thought of replacing the $r$'s with $r+1$ for the $b_{r+1}$ but doing so still didn't make much sense to me..

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry for the late reply! I was clarifying with others if there is indeed a typo but there isn't as it is from a textbook in combinatorics..

Comment: That’s okay: I was asleep much of that time anyway! It’s okay, and I’m deleting my earlier comment (and fixing my answer). I just realized that I misread the problem: I didn’t notice that in the second version there were *two* objects required for each of boxes $2$ and $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating functions should be respectively

$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^5}\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x)=\frac{x^4}{(1-x)^5}$$

for the first and second sequences. That is,

$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^5}=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\;,$$

and

$$g(x)=\frac{x^4}{(1-x)^5}=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\;.$$

HINT: Note that $g(x)=xg(x)$:

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n=g(x)=\frac{x^4}{(1-x)^5}=x\cdot\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^5}=x\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^{n+1}\;.$$

Now shift the index in that last summation so that the general term has $x^n$ instead of $x^{n+1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry but do you mean that $g(x)$ is the generating function for the sequence ($b_r$)? Shouldn't it be $\frac{x^4}{(1-x)^5}$ instead? Also, my reasoning for the proof is as follows:

Let $r = k - 3$. Then we have the coefficients of $x^k$ in the generating function of ($a_r$) to be ${k+1}\choose{k-3}$ , which is also equal to the coefficient of $x^{k+1}$ in the generating function of ($b_r$). Hence we must have $a_r$ = $b_{r+1}$.

Comment: @Stoner: Yes, I’d slightly misread the problem; it’s fixed now. By the way, the point of the exercise is very likely that you don’t actually have to know what the $a_n$ and $b_n$ are in order to deduce the relationship between them from the generating functions. (Of course we could also use the usual stars and bars calculation and get the coefficients and their relationship without using generating functions at all.)

Comment: Its alrignt! :) Thank you for your explanation! Everything's much clearer to me now :)

Comment: @Stoner: You’re welcome! Sorry for the original confusion; that was sheer careless reading on my part.